# Is there a formula that if data in two columns match it sums data from another column?

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

What is an excel formula that calculates if data from cells columns A match and data from column B match, then it sums the percentages from column C into cells in column D?

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you want [`SUMIFS()`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/sumifs-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b)

Comment: Scott, are you able to assist me with a SUMIFS formula?